# Mysql, how to avoid multiple joins on the same table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Is there a way (using some mysql programming) to avoid multiple joins on the same table with different alias? For example I have

```
SELECT *
FROM `container` AS `cont_link`  
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_string` AS `sf0` ON cont_link.id = sf0.container_id AND sf0.custom_field_id=60 
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_string` AS `sf3` ON cont_link.id = sf3.container_id AND sf3.custom_field_id=321 
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_string` AS `sf4` ON cont_link.id = sf4.container_id AND sf4.custom_field_id=322
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_int` AS `sf1` ON cont_link.id = sf1.container_id AND sf1.custom_field_id=319 
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_int` AS `sf2` ON cont_link.id = sf2.container_id AND sf2.custom_field_id=320
```

The Join with custom_field_string table is done 3 times, because it has different attributes. How can I do this just with 1 join but mantaining the different attributes.
I have the problem of reaching the 61 joins limit.

Comment: You need to reconsider the design.  I'd say that more than seven JOIN is bad.  You're an order of magnitude above that.

Comment: I cannot do that for different reasons.

Comment: An example of the data that exists in the table, and your desired output, would be very helpful here.

Comment: I just make it simplier, does not matter cont_link_cont

Comment: This can be done with a set of MAX(CASE WHEN THEN END) statements - but it won't necessarily perform any faster than what you've already got.

Comment: @Strawberry the problem for me is the number of joins, for the moment does not matter the performance

Comment: This is the major drawback of an EAV design (as yours seems to be). You should consider creating a "flat" table that contains all the various attributes, each as a column in that table. You could then populate incrementally with triggers, or with an update or insert per attribute via a stored routine or application code.

Comment: @TimBurch I know that, but this is a high configurable system, so I cannot create a table for each (client) configuration.

Comment: cont_link_cont or cont_link... which is it?

Comment: @Strawberry corrected see now

Comment: @albanx: Given the problem you stated, every `JOIN` matters. I would encourage you to share your entire query instead of just the part you *think* is problematic.

Comment: @albanx I wasn't suggesting one flat table per client configuration, but rather one for all the EAV attributes or one per entity type. Anyhow, another solution would be to create a view or temporary table for each set of sixty or so attributes. You could then join the views and/or tables together.

Comment: Alternatively, break your larger query up into many smaller queries, i.e., one per attribute. You could well experience a significant performance benefit that way, as joins are expensive.

Comment: @TimBurch I really used you last suggestion, but that has the problem that I cannot paginate results (using LIMIT).

Comment: @Strawberry it seems that MAX(CASE ... END) is giving good results.. I will post an answer when I will have a definitive solution

Comment: I think this business about the number of joins is a red herring. Indexes are what matters - but what do I know.

Comment: MAX(CASE END) extremly slow really really slow

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `container` AS `cont_link`  
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_string` AS `sf0` ON cont_link.id = sf0.container_id AND sf0.custom_field_id in (60, 321, 322);
```

If only three rows matched, you'd get 3 results here instead of 1 row with 3 columns.